# Rebase a git repository to merge multiple commits into one, but with a merge commit?

Tags: git

This is a problem I've been encountering, probably due to bad habits, but I haven't been able to find a solution to it. Basically, let's say Im working on a feature branch for a while, and I'm being sloppy with my commits so I have a lot of them, and I'm also pulling in develop a couple of times to keep up to track. It might look like this:

```
#jfdaa My commit
#fkljd My Commit
#4kfdf Merge Commit
#43252 My Commit
#25525 My Commit
```

But I'd like it to look like this:

```
#3953h Merge Commit
#fdsaf My Commit
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your commits are after the merge, there's no need for a merge.

Instead of merging from develop, rebase your branch on top of develop. Then there is no merge commit at all. History is nice and linear as if you've been working on the tip of develop all along.

```
      C - D - M - G - H [feature]
     /       /
A - B - E - F [develop]

git checkout feature
git rebase develop

              C1 - D1 - G1 - H1 [feature]
             /
A - B - E - F [develop]
```

This avoids a lot of unnecessary "update" merges which offer no value, they just make the history hard to read.

You can have pull, which is a fetch and a merge, do a rebase with `git pull --rebase` and always by setting `pull.rebase` to `merges`.

Then you can squash and fixup your commits as you like with an interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i develop
```

Follow the instructions in the editor that pops up. See [Rewriting History in Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for more.

Comment: Thanks, great advice!